# Not able to download doctrine 2 library in zend 2 using composer.phar

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

By Executing `php composer.phar install`

whole doctrine 2 library don't get downloaded. 
There is only a instantiator folder. Earliar, I used to same for this.
Dont know if I am doing something wrong or not.
Any help appreciated and correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

This is what I am looking for. Something which I had got few months ago.

[image]

And this is what I am getting

[image]

**composer.phar**

```
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*"
    }
```

**Commands in cmd**

```
user@THE_RAIN d:\xampp\htdocs\ZendSkeletonApplication-master
# php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.jso
n. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.7.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.2.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.1.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.1.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.7.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zendxml (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-code (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-server (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-math (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-uri (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-loader (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-http (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-xmlrpc (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-view (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-json (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-version (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-text (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-filter (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-inputfilter (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-form (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-mvc (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-dom (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-console (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-test (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-tag (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-soap (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-session (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-serializer (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-progressbar (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-permissions-rbac (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-permissions-acl (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-paginator (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-navigation (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-modulemanager (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-mime (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-memory (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-crypt (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-mail (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-log (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-i18n-resources (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-i18n (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-file (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-feed (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-di (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-debug (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-db (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-config (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-captcha (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-cache (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-barcode (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zend-authentication (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
zendframework/zend-code suggests installing doctrine/common (Doctrine\Common >=2
.1 for annotation features)
zendframework/zend-math suggests installing ext-gmp (If using the gmp functional
ity)
zendframework/zend-math suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Fallback rando
m byte generator for Zend\Math\Rand if OpenSSL/Mcrypt extensions are unavailable
)
zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-resources (T
ranslations of validator messages)
zendframework/zend-servicemanager suggests installing ocramius/proxy-manager (Pr
oxyManager 0.5.* to handle lazy initialization of services)
zendframework/zend-form suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha
(ZendService\ReCaptcha component)
zendframework/zend-log suggests installing ext-mongo (*)
zendframework/zend-i18n suggests installing ext-intl (Required for most features
 of Zend\I18n; included in default builds of PHP)
zendframework/zend-i18n suggests installing zendframework/zend-resources (Transl
ation resources)
zendframework/zend-debug suggests installing ext/xdebug (XDebug, for better back
trace output)
zendframework/zend-captcha suggests installing zendframework/zend-resources (Tra
nslations of captcha messages)
zendframework/zend-captcha suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptc
ha (ZendService\ReCaptcha component)
zendframework/zend-cache suggests installing ext-apc (APC >= 3.1.6 to use the AP
C storage adapter)
zendframework/zend-cache suggests installing ext-dba (DBA, to use the DBA storag
e adapter)
zendframework/zend-cache suggests installing ext-memcached (Memcached >= 1.0.0 t
o use the Memcached storage adapter)
zendframework/zend-cache suggests installing ext-mongo (Mongo, to use MongoDb st
orage adapter)
zendframework/zend-cache suggests installing ext-wincache (WinCache, to use the
WinCache storage adapter)
zendframework/zend-cache suggests installing mongofill/mongofill (Alternative to
 ext-mongo - a pure PHP implementation designed as a drop in replacement)
zendframework/zend-barcode suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf co
mponent)
zendframework/zend-authentication suggests installing zendframework/zend-ldap (Z
end\Ldap component)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zend-ldap (zend-ld
ap component ~2.5.0, if you need LDAP features)
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: I think that you need  doctrine/orm package at require..

Comment: @Svetlio Do I need to write something else for that? I am following this link https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule.

Comment: ok remove the line from your composer json after that just run: 
php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module

Comment: I tried but nothing happended

Comment: you don't have vendor/doctrine right ?

Comment: I have added current structure along with cmd commands. This is how I had configured Zend2_Doctrine2 few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
        "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
        "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
        "keywords": [
                "framework",
                "zf2"
        ],
        "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "require": {
                "php": ">=5.3.3",
                "zendframework/zendframework": "dev-master#d6b0afe61149c6d0669743aab5c73285c42cd0db",
                "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master"
}
```

[lee mas aca: reed more here:](http://samminds.com/2012/07/install-doctrine-2-for-zend-framework-2/)